# CentOS not starting after environment change

Tags: centos, environment-variables, login

I created a CentOS machine using a Cloudera training vm with the help of VirtualBox. Then, because I want to use spark on the virtual machine, I installed the java 1.8 version following the exact steps given at [tecadmin.net](http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/).

I was able to install java successfully, but every time I start spark, I have to execute the following three commands as is suggested in the link above.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_91
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin
```

If I don't execute the above commands before starting spark, spark automatically uses java 1.6 version and will throw an exception. If I execute the above commands, then it is running perfectly.

In the end of the above tutorial, it is mentioned that I should put the environment set up command in the `/etc/environment` file so that the machine will use those variables at boot.

I put all three commands in the `/etc/environment` file, but after I do that, the machine is not starting, always staying at the starting stage, giving the following error:

```
Starting jexec servicesDevice, "eth0" does not exist
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/environment` is not a shell script, it's a configuration file for [`pam_env`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_env.8.html) and has a different syntax. `/etc/environment` (and the per-user file `~/.pam_environment` can only contain simple lines of the form `VARIABLE=VALUE`. You must not use shell features such as `export`, quoting or refering to the existing value of a variable with `VARIABLE`.

If you want to use `/etc/environment`, you have to spell out `PATH` in full, and you can't have a different value for root (with the `sbin` directories). It would be better to put a shell script in `/etc/profile.d`: this is executed during login, and it's executed by the shell so it uses shell syntax (but beware, it isn't executed if you execute commands without logging in, e.g. in a cron job).